# Prove that $\mathbb{R}\not\cong X\times X$ for any $X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, product-space

> Prove that $\not\exists$ a topological space $X$ such that
> $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.

My approach was to prove by contradiction: say $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X\times X$ be such a homeomorphism. Then we look at $g_i:=\pi_i\circ f$ for $i=1,2$. So, $f=g_1\times g_2$. We know both $g_1$ and $g_2$ are open surjective maps. Clearly $g_i$ can't be one-one but I can't advance from here. If we can show that $\exists r_1,r_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g_i(r_1)=g_i(r_2)$, then we are done. Any help? Any algebraic topology answer is most welcome as well.

Comment: What's that image of a square under $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @Bananach Are you assuming $X$ is metrizable then?

Comment: No, why do you think so?

Comment: Ah, I might, good catch

Comment: @bof oh I didn't know about this one. Sure it should be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General fact:

> if $X$ and $Y$ are connected spaces and $A\subsetneq X$ and $B \subsetneq Y$ are proper subspaces of them, then $(X\times Y) \setminus (A\times B)$ is also connected.

Suppose now that $X$ were a space such that $$\Bbb R \simeq X \times X$$

Note that $X$ is connected (as a continuous image of $\Bbb R$) and is uncountable. It follows from the first general fact ( taking $A=\{p\}, B=\{q\}$) that for any  $(p,q) \in X \times X$, $X \times X \setminus \{(p,q)\}$ is connected, while for **any** $x \in \Bbb R$, the space $\Bbb R\setminus \{x\}$ is **not** connected. This contradicts the supposed homeomorphism ( which would be preserved when removing a point and its image). So no such $X$ can exist.